# How to assign a variable to a hash_hmac sha256 string or data in php?

Tags: php, string, sha256, hmac, mastercard

I am using mastercard payment gateway .
All works fine if I hardcode the data or string of the hash_hmac sha256.

the working version:

```
$vpcURL = 'https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?';
$secret = strtoupper("MYSECRET CODE");

$data ="vpc_AccessCode=0E5AC9E6&vpc_Amount=1000&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TEST_TRN&vpc_Merchant=TESTSITE&vpc_OrderInfo=123&vpc_ReturnURL=https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/&vpc_Version=1";

$sha256_hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, pack('H*', $secret)));
header("Location: " . $vpcURL . "&" . $data . "&vpc_SecureHash=" . $sha256_hmac."&vpc_SecureHashType=SHA256");
```

but I can not pass the hardcoded value to the vpc_Amount
I am getting the amount from a form where user can input the amount they wish.

So I am getting the amount from:

```
$totalAmount = $_POST['totalAmount'];
```

Now I want to pass this $totalAmount to the $data.
So I change the $data to this:

```
$data ="vpc_AccessCode=0E5AC9E6&vpc_Amount=$totalAmount&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TEST_TRN&vpc_Merchant=TESTSITE&vpc_OrderInfo=123&vpc_ReturnURL=https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/&vpc_Version=1";
```

When I use this the payment gateway directly goes to the confirmation page : `https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/` and the all the values are empty.

I think it is a simple syntex error..

How can I fix this?
how to pass the `$totalAmount` to `$data` correctly?

```
print_r ($data); gives this:

vpc_AccessCode=0E5AC9E6&vpc_Amount=58,258.00&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TEST_TRN&vpc_Merchant=TESTSITE&vpc_OrderInfo=123&vpc_ReturnURL=https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/?vpc_Version=1
```

**UPDATE**
if I update the code to

```
$real_integer_amount = filter_var($totalAmount, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$data ="vpc_AccessCode=0E5BC9E7&vpc_Amount={$real_integer_amount}&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TEST_TRN&vpc_Merchant=TESTSITE&vpc_OrderInfo=123&vpc_ReturnURL=https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/?vpc_Version=1";
```

in confirmation page it shows the real amount and others are empty but still not going to the payment gateway where user can input their card details

Comment: you probably want to interpolate with `{$totalAmount}`

Comment: I can't see any syntax errors in your code. Do you get any error messages? Have you checked your error log? Echo the string before you hash it and check if it looks correct.

Comment: @pvg can you give an exampe of your suggestion?

Comment: That's the example.

Comment: @pvg check the update in question

Comment: Your return urls in working/nonworking example are different, for some reason. Maybe you've got other params wrong as well.

Comment: And have you tried taking the exact working version and changing the amount from 1000 to, say, a literal 500, does it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I posted in first works very fine..

if I change `vpc_amount` to any (hardcoded) values that works..

the problem was when I assign the `$totalAmount` to `vpc_amount` the variable ($totalAmount) holds decimal points and thousand separators.. 
that makes this issue..

I just wanted to sanitize the variable before passing this `totalAmount` to the `data`to make it works..

so I've updated it as:

```
$real_integer_amount = filter_var($totalAmount, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

and now this works fine..

so the final working code is :

```
$vpcURL = 'https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?';
$secret = strtoupper("My Secret Code");

$real_integer_amount = filter_var($totalAmount, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$data ="vpc_AccessCode=0E5AC9E6&vpc_Amount=$real_integer_amount&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TEST_TRN&vpc_Merchant=TESTSITE&vpc_OrderInfo=123&vpc_ReturnURL=https://www.trinitycollege.lk/payment-confirmation/&vpc_Version=1";

$sha256_hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, pack('H*', $secret)));
header("Location: " . $vpcURL . "&" . $data . "&vpc_SecureHash=" . $sha256_hmac."&vpc_SecureHashType=SHA256");
```

@**MagnusEriksson** : thanks for the time and suggestions.. URL encoding did nothing with this issue.

@**pvg** there was no any spelling mistakes.. if I just use `{$totalAmount}` in the `$data` it did not work.. but this needed this : `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

@**miken32** thank you for your answer. I've tried to use your code just by replacing the params with my actual detail.. but it gave me this error "`HTTP Status - 400 E5000: Cannot form a matching secure hash based on the merchant's request using either of the two merchant's secrets`"

I've double checked the spelling and values/params

This may help someone else in future..

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine the receiving server wants commas in the value. Also, you should build a query string like this to avoid problems with unescaped values:

```
<?php
$vpcURL = 'https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?';
$secret = strtoupper("MYSECRET CODE");
$totalAmount = str_replace(",", "", $_POST["totalAmount"]);

$data = [
    "vpc_AccessCode" => "0E5AC9E6",
    "vpc_Amount" => $totalAmount,
    "vpc_Command" => "pay",
    "vpc_Locale" => "en",
    "vpc_MerchTxnRef" => "TEST_TRN",
    "vpc_Merchant" => "TESTSITE",
    "vpc_OrderInfo" => "123",
    "vpc_ReturnURL" => "https://www.examplesite.com/payment-confirmation/",
    "vpc_Version" => "1",
];
$data = http_build_query($data);

$sha256_hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, pack('H*', $secret)));
header("Location: " . $vpcURL . "&" . $data . "&vpc_SecureHash=" . $sha256_hmac."&vpc_SecureHashType=SHA256");
```

Comment: thanks for that clean code snippet.. but I am getting this error now `HTTP Status - 400

E5000: Cannot form a matching secure hash based on the merchant's request using either of the two merchant's secrets`

Comment: Shouldn't `$vpcURL . "&" . $data` just be `$vpcURL . $data`?

Comment: Something tells me that `&vpc_Version=1` shouldn't be encoded with the returnURL, but rather just another param. @RiffazStarr is my assumption correct?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it isn't in the working version, so yeah, a typo all along.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson probably the case. I've edited. Though the second code sample has a ? instead of & so who knows.

Comment: @pvg It's broken because you need to url encode your data. Quesition, is `vpc_Version` suppose to be sent to the `vpcURL` or to the redirect URL?

Comment: @miken32 Just a suggestion, to make the code even more clear, add all params (including hmac and hashtype) to the `$data` variable.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't see the url-encoding problem here, honestly. There was a working sample in which the poster needed to pass a different integer param - that generally requires no url-encoding. They sent some mis-formatted non-integer and also screwed up the url itself, changing a & to a ?. And that's it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not that I think there's anything wrong with writing a clearer, more robust version of the same thing but I don't think encoding itself was the root cause.

Comment: hey guys check my answer @MagnusEriksson